# Listing resources from a resource folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a data folder beside the js folder in resource/static at the backend of my spring boot application.
I want to list its content in a selection for the user.
I was able to list it if I use the File and Path functions of the base Java. But I don't like this solution, because the path could change in different environment of our system.
I can load a file with org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader. I like this solution better as it is independent of the file path of my system. But I did not found the way to list the files in a given resource folder.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I moved my data folder to the WEB-INF.
And I can list the content of it with the following code:

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context; 

public Collection<String> getFileList(String path) {
    Collection<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    Set<String> paths = context.getResourcePaths(path);
    for (String p : paths) {
        String[] parts = p.split("/");
        result.add(parts[parts.length-1]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And I call it with the following parameter:

```
    getFileList("/WEB-INF/data");
```

This solution works if the WEB-INF folder is unpacked during deploy. And also works when the data folder remains in the war archive.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out :)](http://www.uofr.net/~greg/java/get-resource-listing.html)
You can also read about [Java Reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/classes.html)